# AutoLayout Using Storyboard only [iOS]

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want Autolayout using storyboard only for both portrait and landscape mode.
I have two squares in my portrait screen as given in the photo and when we turn it to landscape mode it should adjust in accordingly.

**Following Figure defines it the best :-**

[image]

Comment: See this link: [Rotation with stackview](https://www.natashatherobot.com/magical-view-rotation-with-stackview/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iOS size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html) and specify different constraints for portrait and landscape.

> Storyboards in Interface Builder by default use size classes. Size classes are traits assigned to user interface elements, like scenes or views. They provide a rough indication of the element’s size. Interface Builder lets you customize many of your layout’s features based on the current size class. The layout then automatically adapts as the size class changes.

Here is a tutorial explaining size classes and a example for exactly what you need: [Adaptive Layout Tutorial in iOS 9: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Use size classes. 
for portrait use compact width regular height and set the constraint according to that.

and than select each constraint and in size classes uncheck all classes select click on + and add compact width regular height.(do this for all constraints)

than change the size class to compact width compact height and set constraint properly only for that size class.

I hope it will help you